# continuous availability - DB single point issues

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, high-availability

One of Our new project requirement is:

High availability - When a new version of the application comes out (WAR file), we would like to deploy the new application without the need to restart the tomcat.

After a short research we came up with 2 preferred alternatives to solve this problem:

1) HA Proxy + 2 tomcats,   when a new war needed to be deployed, we shutdown one tomcat node, directing all traffic to other node, updating the first node , restart tomcat, opening the new node for traffic. (eventually 2 nodes are updated)

2) Tomcat 7 Parallel deployment - sounds exactly like the thing were trying to achieve.

Here are some of the issues that scares us from picking one of the alternatives above:

1) since both of the tomcat instances use the same DB, And since we are using JPA for persistency, and since JPA makes use of a 1st level caching. How can both the instances live in parallel with each other? the caches aren't synced. is it a good practice to disable caching for the deployment time? are there any other Technics for that?

2) Since parallel existence of two instances create such a fuss, is it possible to make all the sessions \ users in the old war to redirect users to the new war? hence solving the caching issue?

3) Are there any more parameters we have to consider? are there any other practices that mitigate this issues?